# ¿Cómo guardar información Arrays Dinamicos en C?

Tags: array, c

para un proyecto de clase tengo que almacenar los datos que estan en un .txt dentro de una array dinamica, y lo estoy haciendo con este codigo.

```
void getPieces(char archiu[15]) {

  fitxerPeces = fopen(archiu, "r");

  // Obtenim quants tipus de peces hi ha
  fgets(aux,4,fitxerPeces);
  tipusPieces=atoi(aux);
  printf("Tipus de peces: %d\n\n",tipusPieces);

  tipos=(Tipo *)malloc(sizeof(Tipo)*(tipusPieces));

  //Obtenim com es diu el tipus de peça
  for(i=0;i<tipusPieces;i++){
    fgets(nomTPieces,20,fitxerPeces);
    nomTPieces[atoi(nomTPieces)-1]=0;
    printf("Tipus: %s",nomTPieces); //Nom en memoria fixa
    strcpy(tipos[i].Nom,nomTPieces);
    printf("Tipus: %s",tipos[i].Nom); //Nom em memoria dinamica

    //Obtenim quantes peces hi ha de cada tipus
    fgets(aux,4,fitxerPeces);
    Qpieces=atoi(aux);
    printf("Quantitat: %d\n",Qpieces);
    tipos[i].Peces = (Pieza *)malloc(sizeof(Pieza)*(Qpieces));

    //Obtenim les estadistiques de cada peça
    for(e=0;e<Qpieces;e++){
      printf("\nE = %d\n",e);
        fgets(nomP,20,fitxerPeces);
        nomP[atoi(nomP)-1]=0;
       // printf("Nom: %s",nomP); //Nom en memoria fixa
        strcpy(tipos[i].Peces[e].Nom,nomP);
        printf("Nom: %s",tipos[i].Peces[e].Nom); //Nom em memoria dinamica

        fgets(aux,4,fitxerPeces);
        vel=atoi(aux);
       // printf("vel=%d\n",vel);
        tipos[i].Peces[e].vel=vel;
        //printf("tipos[%d].Peces[%d]",i,e);
        printf("vel=%d\n",tipos[i].Peces[e].vel);
      }
   free(tipos[i].Peces);
  }
  free(tipos);

  printf("prueba [0]=%d\n",tipos[0].Peces[0].vel);
  printf("prueba [1]=%d\n",tipos[1].Peces[0].vel);
  printf("prueba [2]=%d\n",tipos[2].Peces[0].vel);
  printf("prueba [3]=%d\n",tipos[3].Peces[0].vel);
  printf("prueba [3]=%d\n",tipos[4].Peces[0].vel);


    return;
} //Funció per extreure les peces del arxiu
```

Cuando hago el `printf("vel=%d\n",tipos[i].Peces[e].vel)` que están dentro del `for(e=0;e<Qpieces;e++){}` van bien, pero el mismo al final del código siempre da 0. En cambio, si hago print de tipos[].Nom, funciona bien siempre.
¿Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error? Muchas gracias.

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Tipus: Neumaticos
Quantitat: 7
Nom: C5
vel=5 <-- Esto es el printf de tipos[i].Peces[e].vel que esta dentro del for. Aqui i = 0 y e = 0.

prueba [0]=0 <-- El print de tipos[0].Peces[0].vel
```

Comment: Tendrá algo que ver el que hagas free de tipos antes de imprimir?

Comment: Si, era eso, muchas gracias. @Alfabravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La resolví gracias al [comentario de @Alfabravo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350962/c%c3%b3mo-guardar-informaci%c3%b3n-arrays-dinamicos-en-c/350977#comment632903_350962), estaba haciendo `free` de tipos antes de imprimir.

La solución ha sido poner los `printf` antes de liberar la memoria.

Comment: Amigo, acá sólo van las respuestas. Puedes poner la solución con el código corregido para que otros sepan cómo se resolvió. Mensajes como "gracias" o "Resuelto" no van :) De paso, un tiempo después de poner tu respuesta, puedes (y deberías ponerla) como aceptada marcándola con el tick a la izquierda. Puedes editar la respuesta así como editaste la pregunta.

Comment: @AlexCollado no te olvides de marcarla como respuesta aceptada :)